# How to transform my solution into math solution (vector calculus)?

Tags: calculus

Since I've taken a physics class, I'm able to solve the following problem without referring to any vectoring and integral, but I don't think my math professor would approve the technique I'm using.

"Suppose a plane is flying with 500km/h and the wind is blowing toward the SE at 60km/h. In what direction should the plane head so that the course of the plane is due east?"

The way I solve this:

```
xp = plane-x velocity
yp = plane-y velocity
xw = wind-x velocity
yw = wind-y velocity

plane:
xp^2+yp^2 = 500^2 -> Pythagorean

wind:
xw^2+yw^2 = 60^2 -> Pythagorean
tan(wind degree = 45) = 1 -> xw = yw

since desired plane course is due east, yp + yw = 0

xw^2+yw^2 = 60^2
yw^2+yw^2 = 60^2 -> substitution
yw = 30(2^.5)
yp = -yw = -30(2^.5) = 30(2^.5) to the north
xp^2+yp^2 = 500^2
xp^2+(30(2^.5))^2 = 500^2
xp = 10(2482^.5)

plane degree = inverse tangent(yp/xp) = 4.87
```

answer: the plane should head 4.87 degree North from East so that the course of the plane is due east.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler approach would be to draw a picture (not to scale, of course) as in:
[image]

We see that we must have $60 \sin {\pi \over 4} = 500 \sin \theta$, and so
$\theta = \arcsin ( {6 \over 50 } \sin { \pi \over 4})$, which gives the answer you have computed.

Comment: wow, I can see how to implement that picture into line integral. Thanks!

Comment: may I know what did you use to draw that picture?

Comment: I used a drawing tool (that can handle Latex labels) called ipe.